# Find the list of restaurants around a single point

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to Android location/google maps. And I have been playing around with it and gladly I am able to get somewhere with it. However, I am confused about something that I would like to heard from you how to achieve. Is there a wa I can find list of restaurants around a specific geopoint. Say I need to find the closest 5 restaurants areound the geo point (20,30). How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to take a look at the [places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/index.html) and [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/location-based-apps).  Pretty straightforward stuff.

Comment: Thank you, i just wanted to see an example how you can call link from android